Can DataDog RUM captures SignalR events and connectivity status?
We're using a React application that relies on SignalR for real-time updates. Our goal is to track user behavior and SignalR connectivity status using RUM npm packages and send that data to Datadog. I'm wondering, is RUM capable of capturing SignalR events and connectivity status?
